# Extract data from a field in a text file in Python

Tags: python, field, text-files, extract

I am new to Python. I want to know what is the best way to extract data from a field in a text file?

My text file saves the information of a network. It looks like this:

```
Name: Machine_1 Status: On IP:10.0.0.1
Name: Machine_2 Status: On IP:10.0.0.2
Network_name: Private Router_name: router1 Router_ID=3568
Subnet: Tenant A
```

The file is not very structured. It cannot even be expressed as a CSV file due to non-homogeneous nature of rows i.e. all of them do not have the same column identifiers.

What I want to do is to be able to get the value of any field I want e.g. Router_ID.

Please help me find a solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of "Field"?  It is OK when definition of Field is clear even if several kinds of definition exist. IF you cannot figure out the definition, you never be able to code the behavior.

Comment: Is this just a small excerpt of the file, or is it the whole thing? And if it's the whole thing, are you guaranteed that only the field values change, but the field names are constant? FWIW, we can get most of the data using this regex, apart from that pesky 'Tenant A' `re.compile(r'([^:=\s]*)[:=]\s*([^:=\s]*)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to scan through your file. You'd have to define a regular expression for each field you want to extract. For example:

```
import re
data = """Name: Machine_1 Status: On IP:10.0.0.1
Name: Machine_2 Status: On IP:10.0.0.2
Network_name: Private Router_name: router1 Router_ID=3568
Subnet: Tenant A"""
for line in data.split('\n'):
    ip = re.match('.*IP:(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)', line)
    rname = re.match('.*Router_name: (\w+)', line)
    if ip and ip.lastindex > 0: 
        print(ip.group(1))
    if rname and rname.lastindex > 0:
        print(rname.group(1))
```

Output:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
router1
```